# C# How to brighten colors

Tags: c#, colors, fft

Im doing a FastFourier Transform. So the return values are in the range 0-255 with the higher the volume the bigger the value

Now I have different shapes of various colors. Depending on the volume at the same point in the sound file the FFT can return e.g 1 (low volume) or e.g. 155 (high volume)

I need to brighten or (return to original color if 0 returned) the FillColor of the shape depending on the return value (0-255)

So how do I:
a) Scale the return value in accordance to the sound volume (volume 0-100)
b) brighten the color (e.g. Red by the scaled return value)

Note. Its important that the color is brightened if value > 0

An edit for those who think I **DEMAND** help.

```
 private void _t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ret = BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_GetData(_fft, (int)BASSData.BASS_DATA_FFT8192);  //get ch.annel fft data
            if (ret < -1) return;
            int x, y;
            int b0 = 0;
            //computes the spectrum data, the code is taken from a bass_wasapi sample.
            for (x = 0; x < _lines; x++)
            {
                float peak = 0;
                int b1 = (int)Math.Pow(2, x * 10.0 / (_lines - 1));
                if (b1 > 1023) b1 = 1023;
                if (b1 <= b0) b1 = b0 + 1;
                for (; b0 < b1; b0++)
                {
                    if (peak < _fft[1 + b0]) peak = _fft[1 + b0];
                }
                y = (int)(Math.Sqrt(peak) * 3 * 255 - 4);
                if (y > 255) y = 255;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                _spectrumdata.Add((byte)y);
                //Console.Write("{0, 3} ", y);
            }
            if (DisplayEnable) _spectrum.Set(_spectrumdata);
            for (int i = 0; i < _spectrumdata.ToArray().Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    //if (_spectrumdata[i] > mth)
                    //{
                    //    _shapes.ToArray()[i].FillColor = _colors.ToArray()[i];// Class1.Increase(_colors.ToArray()[i], _spectrumdata[i]);
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    _shapes.ToArray()[i].FillColor = Color.Black; //Class1.Increase(Color.Black, _spectrumdata[i]);
                    //}
                    //double d = Math.Round(((float)_spectrumdata[i]) / 255 , 2);
                    double[] d = GetScaling(_spectrumdata.ToArray(), 0,1);
                    if (_spectrumdata[i] > mth)
                    { 
                        _shapes.ToArray()[i].FillColor = ControlPaint.Light(_colors.ToArray()[i], Convert.ToSingle(d[i]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _shapes.ToArray()[i].FillColor = _colors.ToArray()[i]; ;// Color.Black; //Class1.Increase(Color.Black, _spectrumdata[i]);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    _chart.Series["wave"].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            _spectrumdata.Clear();
            int level = BassWasapi.BASS_WASAPI_GetLevel();
            _l.Value = (Utils.LowWord32(level));
            _r.Value = (Utils.HighWord32(level));
            if (level == _lastlevel && level != 0) _hanctr++;
            _lastlevel = level;
            //Required, because some programs hang the output. If the output hangs for a 75ms
            //this piece of code re initializes the output so it doesn't make a gliched sound for long.
            if (_hanctr > 3)
            {
                _hanctr = 0;
                _l.Value = (0);
                _r.Value = (0);
                Free();
                Bass.BASS_Init(0, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero);
                _initialized = false;
                Enable = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Always a lame downvoter. Can you answer the question?

Comment: Always a lame person attempting to get everything done by others. Can you at least show what you attempted to do and why didn't it work? Read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Comment: The first time I saw your question, I passed it by simply because I don't really know the subject matter you're working with. I checked it again and saw your comment, which triggered a response in my brain to click the down vote button. The attitude that demands help is grating.

Comment: Yes.. I demand with all the power of bits ad bytes and everything that crawl at night that you awesome downvoter help me because Im so helpless etc etc.. boring

Comment: @Camilio. "attempting to get everything done by others"? Then what is the purpose of this forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have absolutely no clue what the hell you're talking about, but if you're just trying to take a number 1-155 and amplify it to 1-255, try multiplying.

Some simple math (155x = 255) has revealed that x, the number you have to multiply by, is equal to 51/31 or ~1.64516129.

So, what you would do is multiply your original brightness, lets say 35, by 1.64516129.

35 * 1.64516129 = 57.58064.

You can use the [Math](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) class to round the number to the nearest integer, which you can then use as your new brightness value.

Comment: Dude.. you the only one to ignore all the bull talk and focus on the problem.